# javascript object memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I develop plugin for chrome (background plugin). But, I think that I have memory leak. Could you help me ? When I use chrome profiler I can see

- [compare memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kg1g.png)
- [In the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEZ13.png)
- [30 minutes later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZQWX.png)

  ```
  "use strict";

  var URL = 'https://api.mysite.org/messages';

  var ajax;
  var intervalId;
  var notification;

  function onInterval() {
    updateData();
  }

  function updateData() {
    if (intervalId) {
      window.clearTimeout(intervalId);
    }

    if (ajax) {
      ajax.abort();
      ajax = null;
    }

    intervalId = window.setTimeout(onInterval, 1000 * 60);
    executeAjax();
  }

  function executeAjax() {
    ajax = $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      timeout: 1000 * 10,
      dataType: 'json',
      url: URL,
      cache: false
    });
    ajax.done(done);
    ajax.fail(error);
  }

  function done(rawData) {
    var tmp = rawData.messages;
    if (tmp != null) {
              notify(tmp);
    }
  }

  function notify(icon, newStatus, message) {
    var options = {
      title : 'New Message',
      priority : 0,
      iconUrl : 'icon/notif.png'
    };
    options.type = 'basic';
    options.message = message;
    chrome.notifications.create('', options);
  }

  $(document).ready(onInterval);
  ```

error is an empty function for the moment

Comment: `ajax.done(done); ajax.fail(error);` - where are the vars `done` and `error` that you pass in as arguments defined and what do they do?

Comment: sorry, I have update the code with done method. error method is an empty function for the moment.

Comment: Switch to [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)

Comment: Thanks for your solution.